# Use Google Drive API in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-api

I am trying to use Drive API to upload a file.
Using this: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads

#### My code

here is my code:

```
url = URI.parse("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files")
url.query = "uploadType=multipart"

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
request_header.each{ |key, value| req[key.to_s] = value }

filedata = [ "file", file, { filename: "Untitle.png", content_type: "image/png" } ] 
metadata = [ "metadata", '{"name": "test.png"}', { filaneme: "", content_type: "application/json" } ]

data = [filedata, metadata]

req.set_form(data, "multipart/form-data")  
http.request(req)
```

And it works fine. The image(Untitle.png) is uploaded to Drive as "test.png".

#### Problem

However, HTML5 officially says that non-file field (i.d. metadata) must not have a content_type as optional hash.

The parts of the generated multipart/form-data resource that correspond to non-file fields must not have a Content-Type header specified.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#multipart-form-data

We can see set_form(encode_multipart_form_data) in ruby is following this rule. https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Net/HTTPGenericRequest/encode_multipart_form_data

Since metadata is non-file field and filename does not exist, my code should be like this:

```
filedata = [ "file", file, { filename: "Untitle.png", content_type: "image/png" } ] 
metadata = [ "metadata", '{"name": "test.png"}' ]
data = [filedata, metadata]

req.set_form(data, "multipart/form-data")  
http.request(req)
```

Here, I cut down content-type option.
However, this code does not work　perfectly. The file(Untitle.png) is uploaded, but the name of file is "Untitle.png", not "test.png" as specified in metadata.

I know I can set metadata as json file like this.
but don't want to specify metadata as a file in this case.

Is there a better way to do this?
I cannot use any gems.

Comment: If you're not set on doing it yourself there's a gem from google for this API.  https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client#simple-rest-clients-for-google-apis

Answer (score 0):

You can use this gem for connecting to google drive.

https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby

Comment: fyi this isn't an answer; it's a product/service/library recommendation, and it's only a link.

Comment: thank you for your help. but in my case, I can't use gems.

Comment: there's no need to discourage any sort of answer.